# Can PEX be routed through existing Copper Pipe?

Tags: plumbing, pex

We have a kitchen island with a faucet/sink and the existing copper pipe under the tile floor has sprung a leak.

The plumber is suggesting to run a PEX pipe through the existing copper pipe to restore the water supply to the island without the need to break the existing tile floor.

I did some searches but haven't seen any discussions on this.  On the surface I don't see a problem since the copper pipe will only act as a conduit and there are no fittings in the copper run (it is embedded in a concrete slab and local building code states that all copper in concrete must be a continuous run.

Second Opinions?

Comment: Well, it's going to be smaller pipe, but that might not be a problem. And assuming local code was *actually followed* on the lack of fittings.

Comment: Good point on smaller pipe...but it is supplying only a single faucet and I still think it is larger than the supply lines into the faucet itself.  Lack of fittings will be found when it is actually tried....Thanks for reply.

Comment: A camera through the pipe run (borescope) would confirm that there are no fittings or other damage to the copper that would end up damaging the outside of the PEX as it slides through.

Comment: What size is the existing pipe?

Comment: The problem I foresee is any 90 Degree turns which will be too sharp.  If these turns are exposed, the elbow could be cutoff and reamed and a loop put in the plex at these junctions.

Comment: We must be talking about soft copper, which would be the only way to achieve a continuous run and wouldn't have fittings in the slab.

Comment: Yes, this is some sort of soft copper.  Houses were built in the 1980's with slabs and county building code required all pipes embedded in the slabs to be inside a plastic sheath and have no fittings below grade.  I have seen plumbers run fish tapes from one wall and come out the other wall through the floor and am pretty confident there are no fittings.  These homes are susceptible to pinhole leaks and with the sheathed pipes that means the water does not go 'down'...instead if fills the sheathing and ends up in the house  overflowing out the sheathing in the walls.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact -- 3/4" copper pipe goes throught the floor. Showed photos of another install where the PEX fit.

Comment: Standard practice in California. All 90s in slab are sweeps and continuous soft copper . All tees are above slab inside walls usually near fixtures .

Comment: This question is literally asking for opinions. Don't know how we missed closing it 2 years ago...

Comment: Wonder how this worked out? Standard installation in Dallas supposedly were soft copper runs without joints in and below the slab, therefore long radius curves as the soft copper comes up through the slab. Could be all 3/4" soft copper. Just above the slab connects to hard copper sweated fittings to 1/2" hard copper. 1/2" PEX fits easily inside 3/4" hard copper. Presume it fits inside 3/4" soft copper.